# Can't find resource files in any of the iOS simulator folders

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have 4 files in my Xamarin.Forms project that reside in a folder named MiscFiles.  The build action for each is set to Content and Copy to Output is set to CopyAlways.  The first 2 files are database files that have a ".db" extension. The other 2 files are resource files named StaticResources.Resources.resources and TestClient.Resources.resources.

The files are being used by a .Net Standard library which is referenced by the Xamarin.Forms project and also a separate WinForms project.  The Xamarin.Forms projects just need to deploy the files with the app and pass  the file path to the Standard Library.

I was expecting that when the projects are built that all 4 files would be copied to the Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData path which on iOS resolves to:

```
/Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A1415D63-CE56-4AA2-B8FB-B89B498E70AE/data/Containers/Data/Application/0682337D-1832-4640-8A90-2DFC525901DD/Documents/
```

The db files are always present in the Documents folder but the resources files never show up.  Are the resource files just not being copied or are they being copied to a different folder?  Does Xamarin treat the resources files differently somehow?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=vswin#loading-files-embedded-as-resources

Comment: @EvZ Thanks, I think this is the right approach but will need to take it up with the  WinForms dev who is on vacation at the moment.  Do you know of any way for me to get the files copied to the documents folder in the meantime?

Comment: @Bo73 All "bundled" files in an app package (ipa/apk) are either going to be read-only "native" asset/bundle-based files or .Net assembly-based embedded files. With either approach you will obtain a Stream to those file(s) and copy that stream to an OS-based file in a directory of your choosing. (Personally I avoid assembly resource-based files as they become permanent memory bloat, etc...)

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks that did the trick; curious as to why I don't have to do this for the db files?

Comment: @Bo73 The iOS Simulator is just a "simulator" and is limited in how it applies device "emulation" style features and is actually using the macOS filesystem, try that on an Android "emulator", a physical iOS device or Android device and it will act differently.